# Different background color for each table row based on a column value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DataTable with a dynamic number of rows based on what filters the user selects. I'm trying to have a distinct background color for each row that has a different value in a column.

```
releaseTable = $('#release-target-table').DataTable()
var colors = ["red", "black", "purple", "blue", "gray", "green"];
var scores = releaseTable.column(1).data()
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length;i++){
    $("td:contains(" + scores[i] + ")").closest('tr').css("background-color", colors[i]);
    }
```

The problem that I'm facing is that only the first six rows are getting colored.
How can I make this work for a dynamic number of rows (could be more than 100)?

The column on which the logic is based has 34 different values as of now, but the number may increase in the future. Even if I add 34 colors in the array that would not help me because I can have multiple rows with the same value in the column used for the color logic but with different values in another column.

Comment: Could you please post sufficient code that we can reproduce your problem? Your HTML is required as well as the jQuery (including a link to the relevant plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution using the better rowcallback

Partial since I did not manage to force the color on the even/odd rows if you use table-striped

If you do not have striped tables it should work.

I would know more, had you posted your HTML. Change the data[3] to match your code

```js
const colors = ["red", "black", "purple", "blue", "gray", "green"];
const scores = ["14.97", "0", "14.44"]; // must be string or change the test
var oTable = $('#release-target-table').DataTable({
  rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
    const idx = scores.findIndex(score => score === data[3])
    if (idx != -1) $(row).addClass(colors[idx]);
  }
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red !important
}

.black {
  color: black !important
}

.purple {
  color: purple !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables@1.10.18/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
"></script>
<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatables@1.10.18/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">
<table id="release-target-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Beer</th>
      <th>Wine</th>
      <th>Spirits</th>
      <th>Other</th>
      <th>Score</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Estonia</td>
      <td>EE</td>
      <td>14.97</td>
      <td>5.87</td>
      <td>1.65</td>
      <td>5.64</td>
      <td>1.81</td>
      <td>3 - Medium Risky</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Belarus</td>
      <td>BY</td>
      <td>14.44</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>0.75</td>
      <td>6.73</td>
      <td>4.46</td>
      <td>4 - Very Risky</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```